# Gradle: Resolving dependency "Could not parse POM"

Tags: gradle, artifactory

I published an artifact to our organization's Artifactory repo and now I am trying to download it and getting an NPE

Gradle Version: `2.7`

Artifactory Plugin: `classpath "org.jfrog.buildinfo:build-info-extractor-gradle:4.3.0"`

Dependency

```
dependencies {
        compile(group: 'com.here.scbe', name: 'ScbeCommon', version: '3.73')
}
```

getting the following output

```
* Where:
Build file '/usr/local/social-analytics/ScbeKinesisConsumer/build.gradle' line: 43

* What went wrong:
Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':ScbeKinesisConsumer:runtime'.
> Could not resolve com.here.scbe:ScbeCommon:3.73.
  Required by:
      social-analytics:ScbeKinesisConsumer:unspecified
      social-analytics:ScbeKinesisConsumer:unspecified > social-analytics:ScbeBoard:unspecified
   > Could not resolve com.here.scbe:ScbeCommon:3.73.
      > Could not parse POM https://artifactory.in.here.com/artifactory/scbe-release-local/com/here/scbe/ScbeCommon/3.73/ScbeCommon-3.73.pom
         > java.lang.NullPointerException (no error message)
   > Could not resolve com.here.scbe:ScbeCommon:3.73.
      > Could not parse POM https://artifactory.in.here.com/artifactory/scbe-release-local/com/here/scbe/ScbeCommon/3.73/ScbeCommon-3.73.pom
```

.
.
.

```
* Exception is:
org.gradle.api.artifacts.ResolveException: Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':ScbeKinesisConsumer:runtime'.
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.DefaultLenientConfiguration.rethrowFailure(DefaultLenientConfiguration.java:62)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.DefaultResolvedConfiguration.rethrowFailure(DefaultResolvedConfiguration.java:36)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.SelfResolvingDependencyConfigurationResolver$FilesAggregatingResolvedConfiguration.rethrowFailure(SelfResolvingDependencyConfigurationResolver.java:112)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.ErrorHandlingConfigurationResolver$ErrorHandlingResolvedConfiguration.rethrowFailure(ErrorHandlingConfigurationResolver.java:189)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.configurations.DefaultConfiguration$ConfigurationFileCollection.getFiles(DefaultConfiguration.java:644)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.configurations.DefaultConfiguration.getFiles(DefaultConfiguration.java:280)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.configurations.DefaultConfiguration_Decorated.getFiles(Unknown Source)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.file.AbstractFileCollection.iterator(AbstractFileCollection.java:62)
    at build_djhx7d7btr97s0fb8sjfrc6d5$_run_closure2_closure7.doCall(/usr/local/social-analytics/ScbeKinesisConsumer/build.gradle:43)
    at build_djhx7d7btr97s0fb8sjfrc6d5$_run_closure2_closure7.doCall(/usr/local/social-analytics/ScbeKinesisConsumer/build.gradle)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.file.collections.DefaultFileCollectionResolveContext.doResolve(DefaultFileCollectionResolveContext.java:115)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.file.collections.DefaultFileCollectionResolveContext.resolveAsFileTrees(DefaultFileCollectionResolveContext.java:78)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.file.collections.BuildDependenciesOnlyFileCollectionResolveContext$BuildableFileTreeInternalConverter.convertInto(BuildDependenciesOnlyFileCollectionResolveContext.java:50)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.file.collections.DefaultFileCollectionResolveContext.doResolve(DefaultFileCollectionResolveContext.java:101)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.file.collections.DefaultFileCollectionResolveContext.resolveAsFileTrees(DefaultFileCollectionResolveContext.java:78)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.file.CompositeFileCollection$1.resolve(CompositeFileCollection.java:88)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.file.CompositeFileTree$FilteredFileTree.resolve(CompositeFileTree.java:92)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.file.collections.DefaultFileCollectionResolveContext.resolveNested(DefaultFileCollectionResolveContext.java:146)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.file.collections.DefaultFileCollectionResolveContext.doResolve(DefaultFileCollectionResolveContext.java:104)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.file.collections.DefaultFileCollectionResolveContext.resolveAsFileTrees(DefaultFileCollectionResolveContext.java:78)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.file.collections.BuildDependenciesOnlyFileCollectionResolveContext$BuildableFileTreeInternalConverter.convertInto(BuildDependenciesOnlyFileCollectionResolveContext.java:50)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.file.collections.DefaultFileCollectionResolveContext.doResolve(DefaultFileCollectionResolveContext.java:101)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.file.collections.DefaultFileCollectionResolveContext.resolveAsFileCollections(DefaultFileCollectionResolveContext.java:85)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.file.collections.BuildDependenciesOnlyFileCollectionResolveContext.resolveAsBuildables(BuildDependenciesOnlyFileCollectionResolveContext.java:43)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.file.CompositeFileCollection.addDependencies(CompositeFileCollection.java:136)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.file.CompositeFileCollection$3.resolve(CompositeFileCollection.java:124)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.CachingTaskDependencyResolveContext$TaskGraphImpl.getNodeValues(CachingTaskDependencyResolveContext.java:86)
    at org.gradle.internal.graph.CachingDirectedGraphWalker$GraphWithEmpyEdges.getNodeValues(CachingDirectedGraphWalker.java:202)
    at org.gradle.internal.graph.CachingDirectedGraphWalker.doSearch(CachingDirectedGraphWalker.java:112)
    at org.gradle.internal.graph.CachingDirectedGraphWalker.findValues(CachingDirectedGraphWalker.java:64)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.CachingTaskDependencyResolveContext.doResolve(CachingTaskDependencyResolveContext.java:74)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.CachingTaskDependencyResolveContext.resolve(CachingTaskDependencyResolveContext.java:63)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.CachingTaskDependencyResolveContext.getDependencies(CachingTaskDependencyResolveContext.java:53)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.realizedDependencies(DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.java:181)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.addToTaskGraph(DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.java:138)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.addTasks(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:98)
    at org.gradle.execution.TaskNameResolvingBuildConfigurationAction.configure(TaskNameResolvingBuildConfigurationAction.java:47)
    at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildConfigurationActionExecuter.configure(DefaultBuildConfigurationActionExecuter.java:48)
    at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildConfigurationActionExecuter.access$000(DefaultBuildConfigurationActionExecuter.java:25)
    at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildConfigurationActionExecuter$1.proceed(DefaultBuildConfigurationActionExecuter.java:54)
    at org.gradle.execution.DefaultTasksBuildExecutionAction.configure(DefaultTasksBuildExecutionAction.java:44)
    at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildConfigurationActionExecuter.configure(DefaultBuildConfigurationActionExecuter.java:48)
    at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildConfigurationActionExecuter.access$000(DefaultBuildConfigurationActionExecuter.java:25)
    at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildConfigurationActionExecuter$1.proceed(DefaultBuildConfigurationActionExecuter.java:54)
    at org.gradle.execution.ExcludedTaskFilteringBuildConfigurationAction.configure(ExcludedTaskFilteringBuildConfigurationAction.java:47)
    at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildConfigurationActionExecuter.configure(DefaultBuildConfigurationActionExecuter.java:48)
    at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildConfigurationActionExecuter.select(DefaultBuildConfigurationActionExecuter.java:36)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher$3.run(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:144)
    at org.gradle.internal.Factories$1.create(Factories.java:22)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:90)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:52)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuildStages(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:141)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.access$200(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:33)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher$1.create(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:100)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher$1.create(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:94)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:90)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:62)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuild(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:94)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.run(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:83)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter$DefaultBuildController.run(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:94)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ExecuteBuildActionRunner.run(ExecuteBuildActionRunner.java:28)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.ChainingBuildActionRunner.run(ChainingBuildActionRunner.java:35)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:43)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:28)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.execute(ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.java:77)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.execute(ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.java:47)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ExecuteBuild.doBuild(ExecuteBuild.java:52)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:36)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.WatchForDisconnection.execute(WatchForDisconnection.java:37)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ResetDeprecationLogger.execute(ResetDeprecationLogger.java:26)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.RequestStopIfSingleUsedDaemon.execute(RequestStopIfSingleUsedDaemon.java:34)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput$2.call(ForwardClientInput.java:74)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput$2.call(ForwardClientInput.java:72)
    at org.gradle.util.Swapper.swap(Swapper.java:38)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput.execute(ForwardClientInput.java:72)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.health.DaemonHealthTracker.execute(DaemonHealthTracker.java:47)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.LogToClient.doBuild(LogToClient.java:66)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:36)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.EstablishBuildEnvironment.doBuild(EstablishBuildEnvironment.java:71)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:36)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.health.HintGCAfterBuild.execute(HintGCAfterBuild.java:41)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy$1.run(StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy.java:50)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.DaemonStateCoordinator$1.run(DaemonStateCoordinator.java:246)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:54)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.StoppableExecutorImpl$1.run(StoppableExecutorImpl.java:40)
Caused by: org.gradle.internal.resolve.ModuleVersionResolveException: Could not resolve com.here.scbe:ScbeCommon:3.73.
Required by:
    social-analytics:ScbeKinesisConsumer:unspecified
    social-analytics:ScbeKinesisConsumer:unspecified > social-analytics:ScbeBoard:unspecified
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.ivyresolve.RepositoryChainComponentMetaDataResolver.resolveModule(RepositoryChainComponentMetaDataResolver.java:83)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.ivyresolve.RepositoryChainComponentMetaDataResolver.resolve(RepositoryChainComponentMetaDataResolver.java:59)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.resolveengine.ComponentResolversChain$ComponentMetaDataResolverChain.resolve(ComponentResolversChain.java:80)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.clientmodule.ClientModuleResolver.resolve(ClientModuleResolver.java:44)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.resolveengine.graph.DependencyGraphBuilder$ModuleVersionResolveState.resolve(DependencyGraphBuilder.java:560)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.resolveengine.graph.DependencyGraphBuilder$ModuleVersionResolveState.getMetaData(DependencyGraphBuilder.java:570)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.resolveengine.graph.DependencyGraphBuilder$DependencyEdge.calculateTargetConfigurations(DependencyGraphBuilder.java:256)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.resolveengine.graph.DependencyGraphBuilder$DependencyEdge.attachToTargetConfigurations(DependencyGraphBuilder.java:230)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.resolveengine.graph.DependencyGraphBuilder.traverseGraph(DependencyGraphBuilder.java:137)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.resolveengine.graph.DependencyGraphBuilder.resolve(DependencyGraphBuilder.java:75)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.resolveengine.DefaultArtifactDependencyResolver$1.execute(DefaultArtifactDependencyResolver.java:90)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.resolveengine.DefaultArtifactDependencyResolver$1.execute(DefaultArtifactDependencyResolver.java:80)
    at org.gradle.internal.Transformers$4.transform(Transformers.java:137)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.DefaultIvyContextManager.withIvy(DefaultIvyContextManager.java:61)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.DefaultIvyContextManager.withIvy(DefaultIvyContextManager.java:39)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.resolveengine.DefaultArtifactDependencyResolver.resolve(DefaultArtifactDependencyResolver.java:80)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.CacheLockingArtifactDependencyResolver$1.run(CacheLockingArtifactDependencyResolver.java:41)
    at org.gradle.internal.Factories$1.create(Factories.java:22)
    at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultCacheAccess.useCache(DefaultCacheAccess.java:192)
    at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultCacheAccess.useCache(DefaultCacheAccess.java:175)
    at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultPersistentDirectoryStore.useCache(DefaultPersistentDirectoryStore.java:106)
    at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultCacheFactory$ReferenceTrackingCache.useCache(DefaultCacheFactory.java:187)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.DefaultCacheLockingManager.useCache(DefaultCacheLockingManager.java:64)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.CacheLockingArtifactDependencyResolver.resolve(CacheLockingArtifactDependencyResolver.java:39)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.DefaultConfigurationResolver.resolve(DefaultConfigurationResolver.java:91)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.SelfResolvingDependencyConfigurationResolver.resolve(SelfResolvingDependencyConfigurationResolver.java:40)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.ShortCircuitEmptyConfigurationResolver.resolve(ShortCircuitEmptyConfigurationResolver.java:52)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.ErrorHandlingConfigurationResolver.resolve(ErrorHandlingConfigurationResolver.java:43)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.configurations.DefaultConfiguration.resolveGraphIfRequired(DefaultConfiguration.java:359)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.configurations.DefaultConfiguration.resolveNow(DefaultConfiguration.java:334)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.configurations.DefaultConfiguration.getResolvedConfiguration(DefaultConfiguration.java:327)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.configurations.DefaultConfiguration_Decorated.getResolvedConfiguration(Unknown Source)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.configurations.DefaultConfiguration$ConfigurationFileCollection.getFiles(DefaultConfiguration.java:642)
    ... 89 more
Caused by: org.gradle.internal.resolve.ModuleVersionResolveException: Could not resolve com.here.scbe:ScbeCommon:3.73.
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.ivyresolve.ErrorHandlingModuleComponentRepository$ErrorHandlingModuleComponentRepositoryAccess.resolveComponentMetaData(ErrorHandlingModuleComponentRepository.java:91)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.ivyresolve.ComponentMetaDataResolveState.process(ComponentMetaDataResolveState.java:66)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.ivyresolve.ComponentMetaDataResolveState.resolve(ComponentMetaDataResolveState.java:58)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.ivyresolve.RepositoryChainComponentMetaDataResolver.findBestMatch(RepositoryChainComponentMetaDataResolver.java:116)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.ivyresolve.RepositoryChainComponentMetaDataResolver.findBestMatch(RepositoryChainComponentMetaDataResolver.java:99)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.ivyresolve.RepositoryChainComponentMetaDataResolver.resolveModule(RepositoryChainComponentMetaDataResolver.java:72)
    ... 121 more
Caused by: org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.ivyresolve.parser.MetaDataParseException: Could not parse POM https://artifactory.in.here.com/artifactory/scbe-release-local/com/here/scbe/ScbeCommon/3.73/ScbeCommon-3.73.pom
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.ivyresolve.parser.AbstractModuleDescriptorParser.parseDescriptor(AbstractModuleDescriptorParser.java:48)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.ivyresolve.parser.AbstractModuleDescriptorParser.parseMetaData(AbstractModuleDescriptorParser.java:39)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.repositories.resolver.MavenResolver.parseMetaDataFromResource(MavenResolver.java:199)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.repositories.resolver.ExternalResourceResolver.parseMetaDataFromArtifact(ExternalResourceResolver.java:170)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.repositories.resolver.ExternalResourceResolver.resolveStaticDependency(ExternalResourceResolver.java:143)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.repositories.resolver.MavenResolver.doResolveComponentMetaData(MavenResolver.java:93)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.repositories.resolver.ExternalResourceResolver$RemoteRepositoryAccess.resolveComponentMetaData(ExternalResourceResolver.java:409)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.ivyresolve.CacheLockReleasingModuleComponentsRepository$LockReleasingRepositoryAccess$2.run(CacheLockReleasingModuleComponentsRepository.java:71)
    at org.gradle.internal.Factories$1.create(Factories.java:22)
    at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultCacheAccess.longRunningOperation(DefaultCacheAccess.java:242)
    at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultCacheAccess.longRunningOperation(DefaultCacheAccess.java:313)
    at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultPersistentDirectoryStore.longRunningOperation(DefaultPersistentDirectoryStore.java:114)
    at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultCacheFactory$ReferenceTrackingCache.longRunningOperation(DefaultCacheFactory.java:179)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.DefaultCacheLockingManager.longRunningOperation(DefaultCacheLockingManager.java:56)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.ivyresolve.CacheLockReleasingModuleComponentsRepository$LockReleasingRepositoryAccess.resolveComponentMetaData(CacheLockReleasingModuleComponentsRepository.java:69)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.ivyresolve.CachingModuleComponentRepository$ResolveAndCacheRepositoryAccess.resolveComponentMetaData(CachingModuleComponentRepository.java:297)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.ivyresolve.BaseModuleComponentRepositoryAccess.resolveComponentMetaData(BaseModuleComponentRepositoryAccess.java:42)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.ivyresolve.memcache.InMemoryCachedModuleComponentRepository$CachedAccess.resolveComponentMetaData(InMemoryCachedModuleComponentRepository.java:75)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.ivyresolve.ErrorHandlingModuleComponentRepository$ErrorHandlingModuleComponentRepositoryAccess.resolveComponentMetaData(ErrorHandlingModuleComponentRepository.java:89)
    ... 126 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.ivyresolve.parser.data.MavenDependencyKey.hashCode(MavenDependencyKey.java:77)
```

here is the POM file - I don't see anything obviously wrong with the POM but I am no expert

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd" xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.here.scbe</groupId>
  <artifactId>ScbeCommon</artifactId>
  <version>3.73</version>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
      <artifactId>aws-java-sdk</artifactId>
      <version>1.10.57</version>
      <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
      <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
      <version>2.6.3</version>
      <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
      <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
      <version>2.6.3</version>
      <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
      <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
      <version>2.6.3</version>
      <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype</groupId>
      <artifactId>jackson-datatype-joda</artifactId>
      <version>2.6.3</version>
      <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.googlecode.xmemcached</groupId>
      <artifactId>xmemcached</artifactId>
      <version>2.0.0</version>
      <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>commons-collections</groupId>
      <artifactId>commons-collections</artifactId>
      <version>3.2.1</version>
      <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>commons-lang</groupId>
      <artifactId>commons-lang</artifactId>
      <version>2.6</version>
      <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
      <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
      <version>3.4</version>
      <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
      <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
      <version>3.1.0</version>
      <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>log4j</groupId>
      <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
      <version>1.2.17</version>
      <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
      <artifactId>slf4j-simple</artifactId>
      <version>1.7.12</version>
      <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
      <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
      <version>1.7.12</version>
      <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
      <artifactId>jackson-core-asl</artifactId>
      <version>1.9.5</version>
      <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
      <artifactId>jackson-mapper-asl</artifactId>
      <version>1.9.5</version>
      <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
      <version>4.2.2.RELEASE</version>
      <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
      <version>4.2.2.RELEASE</version>
      <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
      <version>4.2.2.RELEASE</version>
      <scope>runtime</scope>
      <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
          <artifactId>*</artifactId>
          <groupId>*</groupId>
        </exclusion>
      </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <artifactId>commons-id-0.1-SNAPSHOT</artifactId>
      <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.github.fge</groupId>
      <artifactId>json-patch</artifactId>
      <version>1.9</version>
      <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.jayway.jsonpath</groupId>
      <artifactId>json-path</artifactId>
      <version>2.2.0</version>
      <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.thoughtworks.xstream</groupId>
      <artifactId>xstream</artifactId>
      <version>1.4.8</version>
      <scope>runtime</scope>
      <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
          <artifactId>joda-time</artifactId>
          <groupId>*</groupId>
        </exclusion>
      </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>commons-codec</groupId>
      <artifactId>commons-codec</artifactId>
      <version>1.10</version>
      <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>commons-configuration</groupId>
      <artifactId>commons-configuration</artifactId>
      <version>1.6</version>
      <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
      <artifactId>aspectjrt</artifactId>
      <version>1.6.2</version>
      <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
      <artifactId>aspectjweaver</artifactId>
      <version>1.6.2</version>
      <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.here.account</groupId>
      <artifactId>hereAccountCrypto</artifactId>
      <version>1.6.5</version>
      <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <artifactId>json-schema-validator-2.2.6-lib</artifactId>
      <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <artifactId>noa-sdk-3.2</artifactId>
      <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <artifactId>protobufs</artifactId>
      <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <artifactId>protobuf-java-2.4.1</artifactId>
      <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</project>
```

I could be using it wrong (probably am!) but I feel code should insulate user from NPEs?

Followup: FYI I tried upgrading to Gradle 2.14.1 and had the same issue

Comment: I suggest you have a look at Artifactory's request log, to see which response Artifactory returned to the gradle client for the GET request for this specific pom file. This might reveal the cause of this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I found WHAT happened but not the why

So this does NOT work (as described above)

```
compile(group: 'com.here.scbe', name: 'ScbeCommon', version: '3.73')
```

But the following works

```
compile(group: 'com/here/scbe', name: 'ScbeCommon', version: '3.73')
```

So the question really is, in the publishing project, why does

```
group="com.here.scbe"
```

get mapped to `com/here/scbe` in artifactory and not `com.here.scbe`

Secondarily why doesn't the Gradle artifactory plugin handle things more gracefully?

UPDATE: It looks perhaps like the Artifactory repo has a default (Ivy) layout and not a Maven layout. At least that's my best guess at this stage.

Comment: I just had the same error ("could not parse POM"), and it was caused by having only included the `mavenLocal()` repository because I was just trying to create some minimal test for a project I had forked on Github. So Gradle did find my local version of the library, but not its dependencies. The error message was misleading as I checked the POM file structure several times and couldn't see what's wrong. Fixed by adding `mavenCentral()`.

Answer (score 0):

I faced similar situation. I published pre-built jar to nexus repository using maven. Maven projects could resolve this dependency, but gradle projects could not. Gradle gave "could not parse pom" error during build phase. As a solution, I published the same jar by using gradle, not maven this time.

Answer (score -9):

Update your gradle version or use ./gradlew

Comment: Updating gradle for a two years old project, question author may not even remember he asked about it. If you suggest a gradle update, then explain why. What in newer version will work with existing gradle.properties